# forcing use of node v 8x

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm trying to force the use of node v 8x (so that I can use firebase).

I keep getting an error that says:

> The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version
> "8x". Got "8.17.0"

I can list all the node versions I have installed - there are loads of them - none of them is labelled "8x". I can't install "8x".

Does anyone know how to get past this configuration error?

Comment: Which module is this that is demanding 8x?  It would be nice to see what its package.json looks like and to look at the module's code itself.

Comment: If the module is [this one](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/package.json), then it wants a node version "^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0".  This means it wants version 8.13.0 or a newer patch version of 8.x or it wants something greater than v10.10.0.  Probably it depends on something that was back ported to 8.13 and is present in all versions 10.10.0 or newer.  I don't know why it's complaining about 8.17.0 if this is actually the module you're using.  But, you should be able to use something much newer.